# Monitoring received SMS within a service

Tags: java, android, service, sms

I'm trying to create a service that monitors received sms,
the service onStartCommand and OnCreate are getting called, however when I'm sending sms Broadcast receiver OnReceive is not getting called, What is the problem?

Here is my code:

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.myapplication.SmsServices" />

        <receiver android:name=".SmsListener"
            android:exported="true" android:priority="1000">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Service

public class SmsServices extends Service {

```
private SmsListener smslistener;

@Override


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("SmsServices", "onStartCommand");

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    smslistener = new SmsListener();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(smslistener, filter);
    Log.d("SmsServices", "Registered Sms Listener.");
}

@Override

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(smslistener);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Broadcast receiver

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
public SmsListener (){}
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("SmsListener", "Sms received.");
        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                String msgBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                String msgAddr = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
     }
    }
   }
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent( this, SmsServices.class ) );
        Log.d("Main","Service Started.");

    }
}
```

Comment: have you started the service anywhere in the application?

Comment: @AjayKS, Yes on MainActivity, added the code

Comment: enabled the permissions? and make sure your app is on foreground